# facebook PHP SDK and Graph API Explorer: response from query on "object_url" is sometimes different

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve object_url info from addresses like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/1988/180038755381895?fref=ts
https://www.facebook.com/1nkedandSexy?fref=ts
```

The FQL I am using (from PHP SDK) is the following:

```
SELECT id, name FROM profile WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url='" . $url . "')
```

Using the Graph API Explorer I am able to retrieve info on both urls.
When I submit the FQL through PHP SDK, with the following code, only the second url return infos.
Where is the problem (maybe the fact that the alias first character is a number?)?

```
$fql = "SELECT id, name FROM profile WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url='" . $url . "')";
$param = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
    'callback' => ''
);
$response = $facebook->api($param);
```

Thanx!

Comment: does `$url` and `$name` hold same values in your queries?

Comment: yes, sorry... mistyped...

Comment: Using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20id%2C%20name%20FROM%20profile%20WHERE%20id%20in%20(SELECT%20id%20FROM%20object_url%20WHERE%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2F1988%2F180038755381895%3Ffref%3Dts'%29) with your query returns the requested data for the first URL as well, so there’s no general problem. Have you tried URL-encoding the value first before putting it into the query? Not sure if the PHP SDK handles that correctly itself in this case.

Comment: Yes, tried with urlencode() and rawurlencode()... same result: graph does not return data. Could it be a permissions problem? But this query does not require particular permissions, right?